# Compile/Translate Microsoft COM IDL to Idiomatic C++?

Tags: c++, qt, com, mfc, idl

I'm working on a fairly large project written primarily in C++ using MFC. We are tasked to gradually port this application to use Qt. Years ago, a wrapper around much of our functionality was written using COM. I feel using the COM wrapper from the new Qt code will help isolate code that would force dependencies on MFC. Unfortunately, we're also being asked to ween our use of COM/ActiveX. So, introducing new consumers of our COM wrapper in Qt isn't ideal. Visual Studio has a class wizard that will generate a C++ class based on an interface in a TLB file, but it's dependent on MFC and the interface still exposes COM (`LPDISPATCH`, `SAFEARRAY*`, etc).

With all that said, does anyone know of a tool (free or commercial) that will take a Microsoft IDL file and convert it to C++, who's interfaces aren't dependent on MFC nor COM?

Comment: Things You Should Never Do, Part 1: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Comment: And no, universally adopted binary interface standards don't grow on trees.  Qt is doing pretty well but it certainly isn't universal.

Comment: I'm not looking to throw out code. I want to reuse it, but avoid adding a direct dependence on a "legacy" technology in new implementations. I'm also not concerned with binary compatibility, I just want a collection of headers with a wrapper library to link against instead of importing TLBs and handling COM interfaces directly.

Comment: You already have the headers, midl.exe generates them from the IDL.  It is unclear why you have a dependency on type libraries, they are only needed by languages that can't handle .h files.  But certainly handy for use in code generators, including the MFC wizards and the #import directive.  In general, you are trying to tinker with the glue that makes major functional components of your app work together.  There's hell to pay for changing that glue, stuff stops working together.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear. Right now we're using `#import` with the TLB in new Qt components and working with the code generated by `midl.exe`. This means some references to `QueryInterface()`, marshalling with COM's GIT, _bstr_t, etc, in our Qt projects. Our system architect learned of our approach and advised that we find a way to not add these COM-specifics to our new Qt projects. The class wizard I mentioned in Studio seems like exactly the approach I want, except it generates MFC-specific code. I was simply hoping a similar tool exists that creates more standard C++ friendly code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and working with the code generated by midl.exe

That's hang-up number one.  Midl.exe does *not* generate code, it only generates declarations.  Pure virtual classes in C++, only method declarations with *no* implementations.  Either to a .h file or to a .tlb type library file.  The type library is handy because it is easy to read by tooling, having a restricted sub-set of COM called Automation.  And implemented by just about any language runtime on Windows.

Key point is that these are just declarations, the glue that makes code written in different modules and/or different languages or class libraries work together.  *Very* important in large projects, interfaces tie the pieces together.

> Our system architect learned of our approach and advised that we find a way to not add these COM-specifics to our new Qt projects.

That's singularly unhelpful advice.  "Don't do that" is something my doctor tells me when it hurts to put my arm behind my back.  I can live with that, I have a good alternative and can just turn around.  In your case I would have to demand *more* from the architect.  He's messing with the body parts, he's separating the torso from the legs and head and feet and hands.  Brain utterly disjointed.  The very glue that makes the different chunks of code you have now work together.  Break that interface and you'll seriously break your app, Netscape style.

Beware of the astronaut architect (another Spolsky favorite) that's happy to force you into something that *he* understands but doesn't have to implement.  Demand a reasonable alternative, an *architectural* approach since breaking the interfaces has a deep architectural impact on your app.  Those MFC classes that everybody *implemented* from the interfaces are pretty much junk when you change the interface.  Rewriting them all into Q classes is going to seriously keep you unproductive for a while.  And is devastatingly boring code to write.  Only to produce the same thing, with more bugs.  Things You Should Never Do, part 2.

Comment: Thanks for the astronaut architect reference, sounds very familiar! However, I still feel like you consider this idea to be either a waste of time, or generally nonsensical. I'm simply looking to isolate the COM-specific code into the internals of a single wrapper library. That means I want to take a `_com_ptr_t<IMyIter>` and wrap it in a normal looking C++ class. Instead of returning a `_bstr_t`, I want the wrapper to return either a `wchar_t*`, or a `std::wstring`, so it should do that conversion internally. Is this really all that bad? The VS wizard does this, but creates MFC-based code.

Comment: Well, looks like a waste of breath, but why don't you just plow ahead?  You already have the C++ declarations, you find them in the .tlh files generated by the #import directive.  Just rename them to .h, rewrite them the way you want them, throw away the .idl files and fix all the auto-generated code.

Comment: I was talking to a coworker and he suggested the same approach, but I wanted a "second opinion". I'll trust your 257k reputation and consider this the opinion I was looking for. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to keep using Visual C++, a solution would be to use the plain compiler support for COM.

You need to #import your TLB file

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Then you can make use of the COM compiler support to handle the COM object instances,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h31ekh7e.aspx